# Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator HAXM installer - not compatible with Windows

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, intel-graphics, android-studio, intel-haxm

After installing Windows 10, I ran into a problem with SDK Manager.
After downloading Android Studio, I started building and running my applications, and I realized my emulator is *very* slow.

When I open the Android SDK manager I see this:

[image: SDK Manager]

I spent two hours searching Google for a solution, but with no luck. VT-x is enabled in my BIOS, and fully working:

[image: [VT on]

I downloaded the installer from Intel's website, and nothing has changed after installing HAXM from there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

1. download HAXM from Intel. [Click here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)
2. Unzip the file and Run intelhaxm-android.exe.
3. Run silent_install.bat.

**Before that checked the BIOS of your system, the virtualization is already on.**